# Hiding root category and showing sub categories as menu

Tags: php, css, magento, drop-down-menu

see the image please. My site is located [here](http://www.tenniskarma.com/)

[image]

after shifting the domain, menu has messed up...I want to hide root category and I want to show sub categories as main menu. I want the sub sub categories as drop down menu ( these are already dropdown)

can somebody guide me how I can do it?
any help please?

Comment: found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364950/show-sub-category-instead-of-root-in-menu/14366553#14366553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a couple of reasons for this to happen.

**Reason 1 - incorrect category structure**

1. Your category structure inside the magento CMS needs to have all nav item categories coming from the root category. You may need to drag and drop them into the root category. See the screenshot below for an example:

[image]

**Reason 2 - Theme changes**

1. In your current themes layout folder (app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout/) open page.xml.
2. Find the section that starts with the this block opening: 
   `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">` and then check inside it for info about what template renders your menu. In the case below it's page/html/topmenu.phtml

   ```
   <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
   <label>Navigation Bar</label>
   <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
   </block>
   ```
3. The theme you are using may be using a custom navigation template.
   Check the template which renders the top navigation:
   (app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml).
   The code should be as below:

   ```
   <?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
    <?php if($_menu): ?>
     <div class="nav-container">
       <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <?php endif ?>
   ```

Comment: thanks for such a detail explanation....I have checked option 3 already and its okay...now checking option one and option 2...CATEGORIES being shown on main menu is the name of my root category..

Comment: can you take a screenshot of how your categories look in admin, like the one i have above?

Comment: my category structure is very same...only difference is the root has name Categories, while in your snapshop, there is no name for root category

Comment: after so many tries, I have asked the question here again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364950/show-sub-category-instead-of-root-in-menu