# Show sub category instead of Root in Menu

Tags: php, css, magento, drop-down-menu

before domain transfer  My menu looked like

[image]

I cant understand what happened during the domain transfer and now menu looks like

[image]

My Category structure is

[image]

I am trying to restore the menu as it was before domain transfer, I have tried all the options on my previous question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115028/hiding-root-category-and-showing-sub-categories-as-menu) but yet no success...

Trying to figure it out for almost a week, but Can't..

any idea? any guideline? how can I restore the menu as it was before domain transfer??

Comment: What update are we talking about here? What exactly did you update / install?

Comment: it was domain transfer, sorry, my bad, I copied all the files on new server, uploaded the database on server and ran the Installation script again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on this problem over a week, and finally I got the solution..

Infact, it was a guideline from SO question, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232879/how-to-get-sub-categories-of-a-specific-parent-category)

I edited the file

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOU_TEMPLATE/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
```

and my new code is

```
<?php $_menu = ''?>
<?php
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);

?>
<?php foreach ($children as $_category): ?>
    <?php $_menu .= $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php if ($_menu): ?>
        <?php echo $_menu; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to get the sub catgories of a specific root categories, you can do it like

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);
```

For someone having trouble like me, it might help well..

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

In the backend, go to Catalog->Manage Categories, then click on your root category ("Categories"). 
On the bottom there is a field "Include in Navigation Menu". Set that to "No" and reindex. Then look whether your problem is solved.

Comment: doing so disables all the menu, nothing shows, I already have tried this, and I tried it again now too

Comment: @NewBee Are you sure that it is your root category? Or is there possibly another root category above it? Please show your information of your top category in the database table "catalog_category_entity". Just post the information for the entity_id of your "Categories" category.

Comment: categoryid is 2, and yes, its my root category

Comment: @NewBee Sorry for the bad wording, I did not mean to post the Id, but all the information in the row of the corresponding table with that Id.